# react-jvectormap Error: <circle> attribute cx,cy: Expected length, “NaN”

Tags: reactjs, jvectormap

I'm creating a single page application in which I have used react-jvectormap([link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-jvectormap)) to display online visitors of my site. Everything is working fine but when I am trying to navigate to the other page it generates an error in console.

This is my code file::

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { VectorMap } from 'react-jvectormap';
    import IntlMessages from 'Util/IntlMessages';
    import ChartConfig from 'Constants/chart-config';

    const OnlineVisitors = () => (
       <div className="card">
          <VectorMap map={'world_mill'}
             backgroundColor={ChartConfig.color.white}
             containerStyle={{
                width: '100%',
                height: '100%'
             }}
             regionStyle={{
                initial: {
                   fill: ChartConfig.color.default
                }
             }}
             markerStyle={{
                initial: {
                   fill: ChartConfig.color.info,
                   stroke: ChartConfig.color.white
                }
             }}
             zoomButtons={false}
             zoomOnScroll={false}
             containerClassName="map"
             markers={[
                { latLng: [41.90, 12.45], name: 'Vatican City' },
                { latLng: [43.73, 7.41], name: 'Monaco' },
                { latLng: [-0.52, 166.93], name: 'Nauru' },
                { latLng: [-8.51, 179.21], name: 'Tuvalu' },
                { latLng: [43.93, 12.46], name: 'San Marino' },
                { latLng: [47.14, 9.52], name: 'Liechtenstein' },
                { latLng: [7.11, 171.06], name: 'Marshall Islands' },
                { latLng: [17.3, -62.73], name: 'Saint Kitts and Nevis' },
                { latLng: [3.2, 73.22], name: 'Maldives' },
                { latLng: [35.88, 14.5], name: 'Malta' },
                { latLng: [12.05, -61.75], name: 'Grenada' },
                { latLng: [13.16, -61.23], name: 'Saint Vincent and the Grenadines' },
                { latLng: [13.16, -59.55], name: 'Barbados' },
                { latLng: [17.11, -61.85], name: 'Antigua and Barbuda' },
                { latLng: [-4.61, 55.45], name: 'Seychelles' },
                { latLng: [7.35, 134.46], name: 'Palau' },
                { latLng: [42.5, 1.51], name: 'Andorra' },
                { latLng: [14.01, -60.98], name: 'Saint Lucia' },
                { latLng: [6.91, 158.18], name: 'Federated States of Micronesia' },
                { latLng: [1.3, 103.8], name: 'Singapore' },
                { latLng: [1.46, 173.03], name: 'Kiribati' },
                { latLng: [-21.13, -175.2], name: 'Tonga' },
                { latLng: [15.3, -61.38], name: 'Dominica' },
                { latLng: [-20.2, 57.5], name: 'Mauritius' },
                { latLng: [26.02, 50.55], name: 'Bahrain' },
                { latLng: [0.33, 6.73], name: 'São Tomé and Príncipe' }
             ]}
          />
       </div>
    );

export default OnlineVisitors;
```

Console window Error:-

> 1. Error:  attribute transform:xpectednumber,"scale(NaN)translate(N…".
> 2. Error:  attribute cx: Expected length, "NaN". Error:
> 3. attribute cy: Expected length, "NaN".`